# Routes question: what if I want both a resource to be nested and on its own?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

**Objective:**

Be able to nest a resource, like `records` inside of `users` so that I can access `/users/1/records` to see all of the first users records. But I would also like to see `/records` to see all of the records ( or the new ones, or something like that ).

**Problem**

So I know I am missing something somewhere because that cannot be the way to do it. I know I can have like a static page or some other route for that, but I don't think that is very rails-y.

I would have users, so a user would see their page with their records, but also be able to browse records, so I assumed I would need a more general route for that.

**Question**

What is the appropriate way to browse a nested resource?

*PS I have looked at things [like this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591330/routing-root-to-display-users-posts-for-logged-in-users-and-static-page-for-non) which almost address the problem, but deals with a static landing page for non logged in users, this  **is not**  what I am looking for.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to handle this route later in controllers (never tried), but something like this should work:

```
resources :records

resources :users do
  resources :records
end
```

I think you'll need to do something in records's index controller to check if its called for some user or not.

UPD: Ok, checked it. Check for params[:user_id] in your index controller.

Comment: ok, thats what I figured just wanted to make sure this wasn't some kind of bad rails mojo using resources twice for the same controller